SwiftUI: .textSelection(.enabled) not working in List on iOS 18
In iOS 18, textSelection(_:) not working in List. So, I can't copy text. Works on iOS 17 and earlier. Is there any solution?
// Not Work: iOS 18
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello World")
                .textSelection(.enabled)
        }
    }
}

// Work: iOS 18 and earlier
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .textSelection(.enabled)
    }
}


Also running into this. Haven't found an obvious fix yet.

FB15178192 filed with a repro case.

In iOS 18.1, textSelection(_:) works in List!
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello World")
                .textSelection(.enabled)
        }
    }
}



Have you tried on real device in iOS18 it looks still working on my device. If you tried this in simulator, try to use real device

Thanks for your reply, but it does not work on my real device.
iPhone 12 mini / iOS 18.0 / Xcode 16.0
